# Pagecontrol gesture conflict with swrevealcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swrevealviewcontroller

I have added **swrevealcontroller** in my app.On click of item in table it opens a new view controller.I have added a **pageControl** in that view controller.So first time pan gesture of **pagecontrol** works but on next time pan gesture does not work for page control.Please tell me how can i avoid the confliction of pan gesture.

```
- (void)_handleRevealGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"handle pan gesture");
    CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:self.view]; if(velocity.x > 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"gesture went right");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"gesture went left");
        if(self.isReaveled)
        {
            switch ( recognizer.state )
            {


                case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
                    [self _handleRevealGestureStateBeganWithRecognizer:recognizer];
                    break;

                case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
                    [self _handleRevealGestureStateChangedWithRecognizer:recognizer];
                    break;

                case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
                    [self _handleRevealGestureStateEndedWithRecognizer:recognizer];
                    break;

                case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
                    //case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:
                    [self _handleRevealGestureStateCancelledWithRecognizer:recognizer];
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
    }


}
```

I have modified the above code in order to work but it odes not work.

Comment: actually you were added the swl in self.view correct, your swipe gesture also added to self.view , that the reason it is conflict

Comment: so what is the solution then ?How can i avoid the confliction ?@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: which one you need mostly ...swl or swipe

Comment: I need both of them for font and page control.

Comment: How are you adding/showing different swipe views? Are they from pageviewController or put on scrollview

Answer (score 0):

you have first set the delegate of swrevealcontroller's pan gesture in view controller where you use pagecontroller. for that also add the delegate of gesturerecogniser.

than implement this delegate method of GestureRecongnizer.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {

    if (otherGestureRecognizer.delegate == self)
        return NO;

    if ([[otherGestureRecognizer.view class] isSubclassOfClass:[UIPageViewController class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Allow1 %@", [otherGestureRecognizer description]);
        return YES;
    }

    NSLog(@"Deny %@", [otherGestureRecognizer description]);
    return NO;
}
```

Hope it will Help You.